# Problem executing RIFFT in Cortex-M4

Tags: speech-recognition, ifft

I'm implementing an Speech Recognition System over a **Cortex-M4** processor (STM32F4-Discovery) and I'm facing a problem when a compute the RIFFT.

I believe that I'm passing to the function the vector in the right form, but when I compare the output to the one obtain by MATLAB, it's quite different.

I've also tried to perform an FFT and right after that computing the IFFT, but it gives me a totally different signal as the one I gave it.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Sure but I suppose you need to provide more details. What code are you using exactly, what are exactly the input and output values and so on.

Comment: I'm using the RIFFT function that [CMSIS](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group___fast.html) gives, giving to it the parameters in the way that it's documented, that is:
<hr/>
*X[0],X[N/2] - packed real data: X[0] + jX[N/2]
*X[1] - complex data
*X[2] - complex data
 ... 
*X[fftLen/2-1] - complex data
<hr/>
The major problem is that I calculate the RFFT of an input signal and right after that I compute the RIFFT without touching the vector, and the function gives me a signal totally different from it's original.